# How do I specify default non-template argument initializers in a c++ function template?

Tags: c++, templates, eclipse-juno

**EDIT:  See my own answer to this question for details.  It turns out to be an Eclipse Juno bug, not a C++ problem.**  Nonetheless, the question still covers a useful topic for other C++ template users.

If I wish to create a template class with an argument of "template" type and other arguments of "non-temlate" types, may I.how do I specify this?

Example: An implementation or itoa() but with multiple types, padding and returning a string...

EDIT:  fixed var names in definition.

```
   template <typename T>   std::string    Num2Str( T x, char pad = ' ', int width = 0 );
   template <typename T>   std::string    Num2Str( T x, char pad, int width )
   {
      static std::string   string;
      std::stringstream    ss;
      ss << std::setfill(pad) << std::setw(width) << x;
      string = ss.str();
      return string;
   }
```

EDIT:  This should work across compilers/platforms, g++, VC++.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The above code looks perfectly valid. What part do you have a problem with?

Comment: Well, the problem is that g++ won't accept the initializers.  I tried `Num2Str( 10 )` and get errors about no suitable function found.  If I do `Num2Str( 10, ' ', 0 )` it works just fine.  g++ c++99

Comment: Make sure the default values are in the template declaration in the header file?!

Comment: This is taken directly from my `common.h` file.  The definition is with the declaration.  I must have read that they have to be together in about 100 places.  Can't have a .h and .cpp with templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing up template params and function params.  Why not just this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>   
std::string Num2Str( T x, char pad = ' ', int width = 0 )
{
    static std::string   string;
    std::stringstream    ss;
    ss << std::setfill(pad) << std::setw(width) << x;
    string = ss.str();
    return string;
}

void Test()
{
    auto s1 = Num2Str( 1.0 );
    auto s2 = Num2Str( 2, '-' );
    auto s3 = Num2Str( 3.0, ' ', 3 );
}
```

Comment: Tried it.  Fails with `
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> Num2Str(#0, char, int)  Semantic Error` and with `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, unsigned int) ...and about 250 more characters
'Semantic Error`

Comment: @WesMiller The code above should work. Please post a **compilable** example that reproduces that error.

Comment: Well, it fixed itself.  I know that I fixed it changing the order of includes in my main.cpp, but I have no idea why the order matters.

Comment: Mea culpa; I was premature in my pronouncement of "fixed itself". See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the bug.  Absolutely nothing to so with the syntax or the C++.  It's  a bug in Eclipse Juno.  The indexer doesn't seem to keep up with the build.  Rebuilding the index got rid of both bugs.  `Project Expolrer->(projname)->Index->Rebuild`.  You may first need to do a `Project Expolrer->(projname)->Index->Freshen All Files`.  Finally, in the `Problems` pane, `ctrl-A` to select all the errors then `del` and `ENTER` to clear the error log.

The interesting artifact of this indexer bug is that the IDE doesn't always forget the errors it knew about before the current build.  It couldn't seem to forget the aforementioned two errors and reported them even though they weren't there!

I'm going to edit the OP to add "Ecipse Juno" as a tag hoping it'll help someone from that group.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Wow, how random.  I've seen similar behavior in Visual Studio, but not quite as catastrophic, where the background Intellisense compiler gets out of sync and indicates a compile error that doesn't exist.  After a while, you develop a sniff test.